# Using Generics of Subclasses of Number to Create a Rollover Counter

Tags: java, generics, subclass

I'm trying to create a counter that will rollover whenever it reaches a preset ceiling and resets back to its floor value upon reaching said ceiling.  I have implemented the class and it works just fine.  However, on my way to my solution, I wanted to experiment with Java Generics.  I want to try and extend my counter so that it doesn't only use integers, but instead can use any type of number.  I know that counters typically call for just the use of integers anyway, but I wanted to see if it could be done.

I figured that the code would be similar to below.  However, java.lang.Number doesn't have a "generic" way of getting/setting its value.  Do I need to create my own number class to enable this?  Also, I know that if I do get this working, I need to alter my equals checks so that they have an error threshold for floating point values, this is more or less a modified version of my int counter with what I figured would work for generics.

**Edit:**
It's been suggested that I take a mapping approach where I store an integer counter and keep a increment value so that when I want to spit out a number, I just multiply my current count by the increment value.  However, I don't believe this will fill my exact needs because I don't want to necessarily increment by the same amount every time.  The main focus of this counter is more of a way to have a fixed range number that, when added to or subtracted from, knows how to handle wrapping back around.

I guess the best way to describe it (although probably improperly) would be like an `Integer` that automatically handles over/underflow.

```
package com.math;

public class GenericRolloverCounter<T extends Number> {

   private T value;
   private T lowValue;
   private T highValue;

   public GenericRolloverCounter(T l_startValue, T l_highValue) {
      this.lowValue = l_startValue;
      this.highValue = l_highValue;
      this.value = l_startValue;
   }

   public T getValue() {
      return value;
   }

   public void setValue(T value) {
      this.value = value;
   }

   public void increment(T valToIncrementBy) {
      this.value += valToIncrementBy;
      if (this.value > this.highValue) {
         this.value = (this.lowValue + (this.value - (this.highValue + 1)));
      }
   }

   public void increment() {
      this.increment(1);
   }

   public void decrement(T valToDecrementBy) {
      this.value -= valToDecrementBy;
      if (this.value < this.lowValue) {
         this.value = ((this.value + this.highValue + 1) - this.lowValue);
      }
   }

   public void decrement() {
      this.decrement(1);
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return Integer.toString(this.value);
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by any type of number? If you have a counter, and it's at 5.54643643, what do you expect the next number to be?

Comment: There's a reason we use integers for counting things. Because integers are... countable. There is no notion of a "next real number". There IS a notion of a next double, but it's rather arbitrary and the gaps between doubles is not uniform.

Comment: @Cruncher As kids we all learn to "count by 5's" and it suggests we don't always count in single integral amounts. For example, we count money in units of .01 and .05 and .10 and .25 in the US, since that's the way our coins are divided into US dollars. I don't think its the concept of having a next double so much as incrementing and decrementing by a fixed amount or set of amounts.

Comment: @LeeMeador In this particular case we're talking about incrementing and decrementing. A fixed amount. I'd still rather count and loop by 1's, and map it to the corresponding number(by whatever rule). Counting by .25 and looping to 0 at 1, is not as appealing to be as counting by 1, and looping to 0 at 4, then multiplying it by 0.25

Comment: By the way, your increment function could be: `this.value = (((this.value - this.lowValue)+1) % (this.highValue - this.lowValue)) + this.lowValue`

Comment: @Cruncher Ah, thanks.  I had forgotten to take into account multiple wrap around.  I edited the question to give a little bit more detail.  I don't think a mapping will work because I don't know what the value to increment will be before doing it.  If I did know what the increment value was, that would be a great way to do it though.  I think I may need to bite the bullet and just store it all as doubles.  This started as a way for me to experiment with generics, but I think I'm falling into the trap of having a hammer and looking for nails.

Comment: The increment can absolutely be a variable. If min is m, max is M, and increment is i, and i divides M-m then you can get your mapping of, `0 to m + (0 * i), 1 to m + i, (1 * i), 2 to m * (2 * i) ... and ((M-m)/i) to M` I think. I wrote this off the top of my head, you may have to do diligence on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to also specify an amount by which to count. Default value would be `1`.

You can get around some of this by using the `Number` method `.doubleValue()` and doing double arithmetic.

Here is one of the methods converted to use this idea.

```
public void decrement(double valToDecrementBy) {
  double work = this.value.doubleValue();
  work -= valToDecrementBy;
  // should use some value related to incrementing amount
  if ((this.value.doubleValue() - this.lowValue.doubleValue()) < 0.1D) {
     work = ((this.value.doubleValue() + this.highValue.doubleValue() + 1) - this.lowValue.doubleValue());
  }
  // ... no way to put it back
}
```

But, there is still no way to put the value back that's clean and easy. Since 'Number' only has a few commonly used non-abstract subclasses, you could do some ugly `instanceof` stuff to store the value back. It would look something like this:

```
if (theValue instanceof Double) { // depends on it having a non-null value prior
    theValue = (T)(new Double(work));
}
```

Or you could convert the starting values to `double` when you start and just work with doubles.

```
private double value;
private double lowValue;
private double highValue;

public GenericRolloverCounter(T l_startValue, T l_highValue) {
    this.lowValue = l_startValue.doubleValue();
    this.highValue = l_highValue.doubleValue();
    this.value = l_startValue.doubleValue();
}
```

That does introduce the issues of incrementing floating point values and the rounding/evaluation problem there.

Oh ... and your `toString()` should be:

```
return value.toString();
```

To use the native `toString()` method on the `T` class.

@Crusher's comments suggest another way to do it. Map everything to 'int' and keep a multiplier. Here's some bits of code to show what I mean. (Thanks Crusher)

```
private int value;
private int lowValue;
private int highValue;
private double incr;

public GenericRolloverCounter(T l_startValue, T l_highValue, T incrementAmount) {
    double incr = incrementAmount.doubleValue();
    this.lowValue = Math.round(l_startValue.doubleValue() / incr);
    this.highValue = Math.round(l_highValue.doubleValue() / incr);
    this.value = Math.round(l_startValue.doubleValue() / incr);
}

public void increment(int valToIncrementBy) {
  this.value += valToIncrementBy;
  if (this.value > this.highValue) {
     this.value = (this.lowValue + (this.value - (this.highValue + 1)));
  }
}

@Override
public String toString() {
  return String.valueOf(incr * this.value);
}
```

Comment: I made an edit expanding on one of the things that I'd like to do with this class.  Thanks for the tip on proper use of toString.  I may try the instanceOf stuff but I think the main thing is that I'm making this too complicated and trying to genericize something that need not be.  I mean hopefully we won't be coming up with another primitive number type anytime soon.  And if we do, I think there are other things to deal with first.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer because there really is no way to do this the way I've stated, but this answer gives a valid alternative.